# Link clickability with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is built into layerslider, and in order for a user to get to the next page they have to fill out the current page until it is valid and then they are allowed to move on.

At first I did this by showing/hiding the button but it was confusing my users.

What I'm doing now it changing the opacity/clickability based on if the page is valid.

My problem is that while I can change the opacity no problem I'm having a difficult time getting the buttons to be unclickable (deep link i.e. #NextPage).

My question is, is there a *clean* way to do this using jQuery, or will I have to put a div over it and show/hide that?

********** EDIT *****************

I am using links to a deep link, not html buttons i.e. `<a href="#page2">`

I need to make the anchor unclickable/clickable

Comment: I dunno about links, but for buttons you can use `<input type="button" disabled>`

Comment: it will be hard to tell unless you show us your code... have to tired anything ?? please post your related codes too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the button, simply use:

```
$('#YOURBUTTON').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: I'm going to recode it to use buttons with onclick instead of anchor links.  Thanks !!!!